# How to save all the files in csv from the folder in R?

Tags: r

I have 1500 `.csv` files in a folder, but I am not able to read them directly.

If I open each file, save it manually, I am then able to read it in R.

Hence I need to automate this process of opening each file and saving it in `.csv` in desired folder? Any help would be appreciated.

```
fi <- list.files("C:/Users/Desktop/DL/Test", full.names = T)
dat <- lapply(fi, read.csv, row.names = NULL)
```

The contains of the file are

```
    version 1.3.0                           
info    team    Ireland                     
info    team    England                     
info    gender  male                        
info    season  2006                        
info    date    6/13/2006                       
info    venue   Civil Service Cricket Club, Stormont                        
info    city    Belfast                     
info    toss_winner England                     
info    toss_decision   bat                     
info    player_of_match ME Trescothick                      
info    umpire  R Dill                      
info    umpire  DB Hair                     
info    match_referee   CH Lloyd                        
info    winner  England                     
info    winner_runs 38                      
ball    1   0.1 England ME Trescothick  EC Joyce    DT Johnston 0   0
ball    1   0.2 England ME Trescothick  EC Joyce    DT Johnston 0   0
ball    1   0.3 England ME Trescothick  EC Joyce    DT Johnston 0   4
```

Comment: Please post example contents of a file. Otherwise we are shooting in the dark.

Comment: version 1.3.0       
info team Ireland      
info team England      
info gender male      
info season 2006      
info date 6/13/2006      
info venue Civil Service Cricket Club, Stormont      
info city Belfast      
info toss_winner England      
info toss_decision bat      
info player_of_match ME Trescothick      
info umpire R Dill      
info umpire DB Hair      
info match_referee CH Lloyd      
info winner England      
info winner_runs 38      
ball 1 0.1 England ME Trescothick EC Joyce DT Johnston 0 0

This is what the file contains

Comment: Hey Praveen, [please see here examples of how to post data in an effective manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Consider, e.g., posting the output of `dput(df)` below the original question (not in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are doing something to the csv's before saving them, because otherwise this would be unproductive and would be better to simply create a script to copy the files.

You can use lapply with write.csv in the following manner:

```
fi<-list.files("C:/Users/Desktop/DL/Test",full.names=T) 

dat<-lapply(fi, read.csv, row.names = NULL)

lapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) {
    write.csv(dat[i], paste0('address/to/file', i,'.csv'))
  })
```

Comment: I am getting this error               Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: Try using `dat[i]` instead of `dat[[i]]`

Comment: I am not doing anything before saving.As I am facing issue when I directly import the files ,whereas when open each file and do save as it works fine.Thats why I need to open each file and save it with same name

Comment: are you being able to read the files? can you show me the output of the dat list?

Comment: I am not able to read the file ,I am getting the below error  when I run this code                                                                                                                fi<-list.files("C:/Users/Desktop/DL/odi_csv_male",full.names=T)

dat<-lapply(fi, read.csv, row.names = NULL)                                                                    Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: can you show a line of the csv? What is the separator, is it a comma?

Comment: Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv),yes it is

Comment: It will be hard to help you without seeing your code and the csv file, i'm sorry. You can try skiping the headings first to see if it will read, use the following line: `dat<-lapply(fi, read.csv, skip=1, row.names = NULL)`

Comment: I have edited the question and shared the contains of the file

Comment: I saw it, you need to skip the first line, it is not following the standard. see my code above, it may help you.